Dropbox - createSharedLinkWithSettings return null
I'm trying to get the url from the dropbox function: createSharedLinkWithSettings, the problem is that it returns me: null
I have the dropbox free plan, could that be why?
However I'm working on Laravel 10.
Thank you.
public function generateSharedLink($file)
{
    $client = new Dropbox(env('DROPBOX_TOKEN'));
    try {
        $sharedLink = $client->createSharedLinkWithSettings($file, [
            'settings' => [
                'requested_visibility' => 'public',
            ],
        ]);
        return $sharedLink['url'];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Gestisci gli errori, come il file non trovato o l'errore di accesso
        return null;
    }
}


if you remove the try/catch what happens?

bad request comes out

Make sure to enable debugging

comes out: Spatie \ Dropbox \ Exceptions \ BadRequest
without the error below, it is blank.

Since it's returning 400 this is most likely something related to the token, please make sure the token is valid and present, try running other function like listFolder($path) and see if it does the same thing.

UPDATE : i set up a project and tried to run the code and had the same issue, i found the issue is related to permissions I will put the help as an answer

If you're getting a response with a 400 status code, be sure to print out the response body too, as it should contain a more detail error message.

Since the issue is token related, please go to your app settings and check the permissions you want, especially files.content.write and regenerate a new token after saving the changes.


I already have files.content.write active but it still doesn't work, I regenerated the token with the new settings but it still doesn't work

In the class where I get the method: createSharedLinkWithSettings
there's a comment above that says:
If no settings are given then the default visibility is RequestedVisibility.public.
* The resolved visibility, though, may depend on other aspects such as team and
* shared folder settings). Only for paid users.
Could it be that this method is only available to those on the paid plan? I have the free plan.

Sorry for the late reply. I tried to run the code you provided, but I faced the same issue, 400 with no message. When I tried running it using curl, it showed me what's wrong. It needs the permission for sharing.write, which they mention in the docs. Add it and regenerate a token and tell me if it works. This has nothing to do with the paid version.

I've already tried activating sharing.write and regenerating the token but still nothing.
Anyway, I've given up on it now, thanks.
